# how to run opl code(by caling opl file) in python

Tags: python-3.x, opl

I have a data file inputpy.xlsx and I am converting this file to an opl input language(1 and 0) called outputpy.xlsx, and I have a working opl model that takes my outputpy.xlsx file and outputs to an excel file(oploutput.xlsx) from cplex ide.

However, my problem is I am currently running both of them separately.
First I am running python code to make outputpy.xlsx and than I am using cplex ide to make oploutput.xlsx.

My question is :

How can I call/run my cplex code from my python code, after I created the outputpy.xlsx in python? I don't want to run python code and then run the cplex ide separately.

what I find online is some suggest using python API or doccplex, I am not sure the difference between them. I believe that using python API I have to change the cplex code for the python language, and I also can't find the nice tutorial for this.

Do you have suggestions? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One very simple way to do this is to use `oplrun` instead of the IDE. Using `oplrun` you can run a project and/or `mod` file from the command line. Then you can invoke this from Python using `subprocess.popen()` or just `os.system()` (see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)).

The description of `oplrun` can be found in the reference documentation in chapter [IDE and OPL > oplrun command line interface](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/refoplrun/topics/oplrun_TOP.html)

In order to run OPL directly from Python you could have a look at the [doopl](https://pypi.org/project/doopl/) package.

Comment: I added a link to doopl to my answer. doopl allows calling OPL directly from Python. See the documentation of that package.

Comment: Thank you very much